# Can exe accept parameters in Compact Framework?

Tags: compact-framework

What is the syntax I should use to make my Smart Device app written in.net CF 2.0 accept arguments, so I can start exe in he following manner:

Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");

Should the Main() be modified?
If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you simply change Main to accept a string array input.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks! How come Process.Start accepts the second argument as a string and not string[]? Is that an inconsistency?

Comment: No inconsistency.  It splits them on spaces, unless contained in quotes, just like the C/C++ versions of WinMain.  So `foo.exe bar baz` would pass in two strings.  `foo.exe 'bar baz'` would pass in one.